# Rails 3 post to facebook, do I need an access token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

I have a requirement for my app where I need to post some model information from the app to the users FB wall. All gems (fb_graph & koala) seem to require an access token (which requires me to have an FB app). I want to keep this super simple. I'm confused about whether or not I can use the Facebook Javascript SDK without an access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my research I found that facebook still has the unsupported 'facebook sharer' which used this url https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php and arguments passed. Note, this is deprecated and unsupported, who knows how long it will still work.

So I did something like...

```
<%= link_to 'Back', events_path %>|
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100
&p[url]=http://mycoolsite.us/<%= current_user.vanity_url %>
&p[title]=Check out our <%= @event.title %>"
>Share</a>
```

...and it does what I need it to. Note the ruby embedded inside the code so I can pass model data.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to authorize your app to post stuff on behalf of your user, and the access token is the result of that.

If you don't have to do the posting server side, you could also find a way to use Facebook's [share button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/). The benefit of this is that it's client side, and it can benefit from an existing facebook session that someone might have.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I followed the link you posted, and when I "Get Code" the snippet includes my app ID, which is the access token. Correct?

Comment: I guess you'll still need an APP, as it appears the share button does need an app. This is peanuts compared to getting an actual access token, though. An access token is a string that is basically your application's access code to do stuff with facebook on behalf of an individual user. This is basic oAuth2 stuff, though. This presentation will explain it better, I hope: http://www.slideshare.net/aaronpk/an-introduction-to-oauth-2